# Parsing a variably space delimited list with nom

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

How can I consume a list of tokens that may or may not be separated by a space?

I'm trying to parse Chinese romanization (pinyin) in the [cedict](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=cedict) format with `nom` (6.1.2). For example `"ni3 hao3 ma5"` which is, due to human error in transcription, sometimes written as `"ni3hao3ma5"` or `"ni3hao3 ma5"` (note the variable spacing).

I have written a parser that will handle individual syllables e.g. `["ni3", "hao3", "ma5"]`, and I'm trying to use a `nom::multi::separated_list0` to parse it like so:

```
nom::multi::separated_list0(
    nom::character::complete::space0,
    syllable,
)(i)?;
```

However, I get a `Err(Error(Error { input: "", code: SeparatedList }))` after all the tokens have been consumed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using

```
nom::multi::separated_list0(
    nom::character::complete::space0,
    syllable,
)(i)?;
```

Is that the `space0` delimiter matches empty string, so it will reach the end of the input string and the `separated_list0` will continue to try to consume the empty string, hence the `Err(Error(Error { input: "", code: SeparatedList }))`.

The solution in my case was to use `nom::multi::many1` and handling the optional spaces in the inner parser instead of `nom::multi::separated_list0` like so:

```
fn syllables(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<Syllable>> {
    // many  instead of separated_list0
    multi::many1(syllable)(i)
}

fn syllable(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, Syllable> {
    let (rest, (_, pronunciation, tone)) = sequence::tuple((

        // and handle the optional space
        //              here 
        character::complete::space0,
        character::complete::alpha1,
        character::complete::digit0,
    ))(i)?;

    Ok((rest, Syllable::new(pronunciation, tone)))
}
```